# Filter API Results With Both OnClick and Search Input

Tags: reactjs, events

I'm trying to filter api results based on what the user enters in a search bar or when the specific category buttons are clicked. The problem is that whenever I combine maps  to allow for this functionality I get strange results. Am I writing the syntax the correct way? I am new to React.

```
<div id="buy-grid" className="product-grid">
                <div className="content">
                    <h3>Search for Products</h3>
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
                        <h3>Top Results</h3>
                    </form>
                    <div className="grid">
                        {response.map((element, index) =>{

                            if(element.name.includes(inputVal)){
                                return(
                                <div className="product-card one" key={index}>
                                    <p>{element.name}</p>
                                    <img src= {element.image}></img>
                                </div>)
                            }

                            else if(element.category.includes(buttonVal)){
                                return(
                                
                                <div className="product-card two" key={index}>
                                    <p>{element.name}</p>
                                    <img src= {element.image}></img>
                                </div>)
                            }
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: looks good to me - can you say more about what you expect to see and what is actually rendered instead?

Comment: I'm trying to make something like this: https://codepath-student-store-demo.surge.sh/#Buy ,but in my code doing the above results in my search results not filtering based on the correct value. Instead if I were to type in "x" I would get results that dont include x but are still returned.